# How can I set Properties with xml in selenium?

Tags: xml, selenium

i have xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Enviroment>
<BrowserType>chrome</BrowserType>
<URL>https://dev.leolane.com/</URL>
<ChromeDriverPath>C://Automation/Selenium Driver/chromedriver.exe/</ChromeDriverPath>


<!--Report -->
<ReportFilePath>C:/Automation/Reports/</ReportFilePath>
<ReportFileName>TestReport.html</ReportFileName>
</Environment>
```

I want to use the driver path in my code

my code is:

@BeforeClass

```
public static void  startsSession() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException

{
    System.setProperties ("webdriver.chrome.driver");
    driver.get(getData("ChromeDriverPath"));
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(getData("URL"));
```

when i run the program i get null pointer exception 
How can I set Properties with xml?

Answer (score 0):

chrome driver path is incorrect

```
<ChromeDriverPath>C://Automation/Selenium Driver/chromedriver.exe/</ChromeDriverPath>
```

it should be `<ChromeDriverPath>C:/Automation/Selenium Driver/chromedriver.exe</ChromeDriverPath>`